# best alternative for <slot/> in <textarea> in [ Vue.js 3 ] component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, slot

I want create component with textarea and pass data inside that like

```
<c-textarea> hello world </c-textarea>
```

but the classic `<slot/>` tag not work inside of textarea
what's simplest and cleanest alternative

```
<template>
   <textarea><slot/></textarea>
</template>
```

in Vue.js 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the content of a slot:

```html
<template>
   <textarea>{{ $slots.default ? $slots.default()[0].children : ''}}</textarea>
</template>
```

Basically, this builds the slot manually, which gives you a VNode element, where `children` contains the slot content.

I would really try to find another way though, this is coarse, error prone and most likely not what you want to do.

Personally, I would stick to the `v-model` approach.

Answer (score 8):

You should use `value` & `input` to bind the content instead of using `slot`

Here is the updated version of `CTextarea` component

```html
<template>
  <textarea :value="modelValue" @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)">
  </textarea>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'CTextarea',

  emits: ['update:modelValue'],

  props: {
    modelValue: String,
  },
};
</script>
```

check this [woking demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-s5yvgk?file=src/components/CTextarea.vue)

Answer (score 1):

In script setup and Vue ^3.3 version you could it in a very short way :

```html
<script setup>
   const modelValue = defineModel();
</script>

<template>
 <textarea v-model="modelValue"/>
</template>
```